# How do I see my crash reports from TestFlight/iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded a build yesterday to TestFlight and checked the symbolicated crash reports option, but I have no idea where to find the actual crash reports that are coming in.

It's not on the App Store yet if that matters, it's still in testing through TestFlight, which is why this is important.

Comment: Have you any new information? Did you solve this problem?